# starter project for react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I need to know the best starter kit/generator. I have just tested "create-react-native-app". Is there any generator or kit available for react native projects?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please check your inbox

Comment: @Liam thank you for your advice.

Comment: You can see http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/boilerplates

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can check out https://github.com/teallabs/react-native-init . It is pretty amazing react-native starter kit with codepush, google signin, sentry, react-navigations and all setup steps.